# In JavaScript, how do I merge an array of objects with another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

In a loop, I am trying to merge the contents of two arrays:

```
var myArray = [{a:"a"},{b:"b"}];//first pass in loop
var myArray = [{c:"c"},{d:"d"}];//second pass in loop
```

For the result, I would like to have this:

```
results = [{a:"a"},{b:"b"},{c:"c"},{d:"d"}];
```

If I do this at each pass:

```
results.splice(0,0,array[i]);
```

Then the `results` array becomes a collection of two arrays, rather than a collection of four objects.

I have tried `.concat`, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to merge the objects comprising an object array with another object array without using a combination of `for()` and `push()`?

There must be something simple I have missed.

Thanks

Comment: @Dennis--It just seems like it would be inefficient since all I need to do is combine the two collections. No?

Comment: No matter what you do will end up at its core being a for/push.  You also weren't clear on what it means that "concat didn't work"

Comment: Concat was not working, apparently, because I was trying to merge the first iteration of `myArray` with an empty array.  I did not know that it was impossible to do this.  After adding some simple logic to only call `concat` if there were items in the `results` array, else set `results` = `myArray`, everything worked fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually concat is the right way to go
in your example you are defining myarray twice. hopefully this is not the case in your code. when I try

```
var myArray1 = [{a:"a"},{b:"b"}];
var myArray2 = [{c:"c"},{d:"d"}];
var result = myarray1.concat(myarray2);
```

This must work. if not then please show us the result of these threee lines in your browser

Answer (score 0):

Moataz has your answer, but you mention a loop so you might be looking for:

```
var result = [];
var myArray;

for (...) {
  myArray = /* getMyArray()? */
  result = result.concat(myArray);
}
```

where `myArray` is set to new values each time. You could remove one line by having the logic that assigns the array to `myArray` in the `concat` expression.